# What happens when a task fails maximum number of attempts?

Tags: apache-spark

will failed Spark tasks get new task id after passing the max tried?

After the max try, will the another try send to a different executor with new task id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will failed Spark tasks get new task id after passing the max tried?

Maximum attempts of a task fails the whole stage and hence the Spark job.

Assigning a task is random (across available executors) and it's supposed to be unlikely that a failed task will get assigned to the same executor again (within 4 attempts).